# React Native Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-cli

I created a basic react native app just to practice.
As a first step, I followed the docs below to create a navigation from one page to another:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation

I'm using React Native CLI, and installed:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/native-stack

npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

and I copied the code from the docs to my App.js file. When I'm hitting npx react-native run-android, I'm getting the following error:

**error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-navigation from C:\Users\sh\NewProject\App.js: react-navigation could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules**

I tried to delete node_modules and did npm install - didn't help.

Any idea how to resolve this? thanks

Comment: can u write the package.json?

Comment: show what you copied

Comment: I resolved this by installing the modules step by step, something went wrong the first time.

Comment: You should write more precise questions, and if you find a solution, you should also add it. Otherwise which is the added value of this question in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when `library` is not linked up or properly not imported. Please uninstall and try to install it again step by step.